# Prepared statement ps.executeUpdate() is slow in execution under load

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, amazon-rds, hikaricp

I am currently facing issue on performance of Spring JDBC. I am performing inserts in serie and this is increasing the latency when load is introduced. I am using prepared statements and Hikari CP connection pool.
I have narrowed down the problem which function call in Jdbctemplate class is taking more time.
This is the line - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/06e352822abc1eb0f5858ca9e79e38f8958e3c63/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.java#L546

It is stmt.executeUpdate in UpdateStatementCallback.  What can be reason for this?
I have using connection pooling, prepared statement cache & batching as well. I have checked, the underlying Mysql (using AWS RDS) is not a Problem as well.

is there anything I am missing?

```
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.cachePrepStmts=true
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.prepStmtCacheSize=250
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit=2048
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.useServerPrepStmts=true
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.useLocalSessionState=true
spring.datasource.hikari.autoCommit=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batchSize=200
```

Comment: Could you also check what statement exactly is going into the DB. It is seen that if only "values (), () .." clause is repeated then query takes lesser time as it will be parsed only once. if whole "insert into ..." is repeated, query will need to be parsed again for every insert hence inserts can be slower. However, this will only create a small difference. Other areas to look for is what is actual transaction size (how many records are inserted in one transaction), DB indexes (too many indexes can also slow the inserts. Try to get db state and locks requested to check concurrency.

Comment: In the past I've observed a performance decrease when inserting lots of rows within a single transaction. How many rows are you inserting, and what is your transaction-management?

Comment: @simon I have using a single transaction to insert a single "INSERT " statement.  and transaction management is TransactionJpaManager.